# Add an additional check (bash script) to the sshd server

Tags: ssh, bash

Is it possible to run an additional script during the login process of the sshd daemon/server?

I would like to run an additional command that uses the IP address and the username of the attempt. If the script returns an exit status 0 it can pass, else the login should be rejected.

I could not find anything in the SSHD docs.

Comment: Can't you use `AllowUsers`, one of the `Match` directives or the firewall (iptables) to accomplish your task? I have never tried it before, but perhaps `AuthorizedKeysCommand` is something you can use for your purposes. For authentication, you can also consider using PAM.

Comment: I think AuthorizedKeysCommand is an interesting one. I could make it as simple as a bash script that executes the script. On a 0 exit status it can cat and echo ~/.ssh/authorized_keys or something like that. Will give it a try.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by checking the IP and username? Are you restricting access by IP for specific users, i.e. User A can only connect from IP 1, but User B can connect from IP 1 & 2? That will help us understand.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you may be trying to reinvent ...

You can configure AllowUsers in sshd_config to allow only certain users and you can further restrict their access by specifying a host

> AllowUsers
>                This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns,
>                separated by spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for
>                user names that match one of the patterns.  Only user names are
>                valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized.  By default, login
>                is allowed for all users.  If the pattern takes the form
>                USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately checked, restricting
>                logins to particular users from particular hosts.
>
> See PATTERNS in ssh_config(5) for more information on patterns

Patterns can be quite complex so you could for example use

```
AllowUsers user@192.168.1.? user2 user2
```

and so on.

Comment: We're not trying to restrict a certain IP or user, but would like to let an external HTTPS service handle the request (in addition to the standard authentication process already in place in the server).

Comment: @RobinUS2: https and sshd working together - how are you doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

I won't debate the correctness of what you are attempting. This sshd config 
variable will run a command for every login and you can decide whether to continue the login from this program.

```
 ForceCommand
         Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand,
         ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if
         present.  The command is invoked by using the user's login shell
         with the -c option.  This applies to shell, command, or subsystem
         execution.  It is most useful inside a Match block.  The command
         originally supplied by the client is available in the
         SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable.  Specifying a command
         of ``internal-sftp'' will force the use of an in-process sftp
         server that requires no support files when used with
         ChrootDirectory.
```

You can find a source code example of how to use this option for restricting access in the duo_unix source code. https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_unix

ForceCommand runs in the users context and escaping out of it into the shell is something you will have to take into consideration if you use this method to 
restrict access. My guess is that nothing short of a C program that captures signals is going to be bullet proof enough.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended method to add additional requirements to your SSH authentication is to change the PAM configuration.

The existing [pam_exec](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html)  PAM module allows you to call any external script or command. PAM will set a number of environment variables including PAM_RHOST and PAM_USER which you can use in your script.

Depending on how you stack your pam modules the script can only be called for users that authenticate successfully or all log in attempts.

PAM_RHOST  may actually contain the remote hostname instead of the ip-address, depending on the PAM implementation

PAM_USER  is the supplied username of the user trying log in.